# Blocking upsert in couchbase

Tags: java, couchbase, project-reactor

I am writing a test where I need to upsert some documents(let's say 10) in my couchbase bucket before actually running any tests. So I have a method annotated with @BeforeAll that tries to upset these documents. Now when I try to run the test, the test fails because documents were not persisted by then. In order to wait for these documents to be inserted I am doing something like this -

```
    Flux.fromIterable(couchDocs)
        .map(couchDoc -> bucket.upsert(couchDoc, persistTo)
        .collectList()
        .block();
```

But still when I run the test I can see that the documents were not persisted by then and the assertions fail. Am I missing something here?

Comment: what does your method `upsert` return? Could you also provide its signature?

Comment: What class is `bucket` an instance of?

Comment: @KunalGupta consider accepting an answer if it works for you.

Comment: The reason documents weren't getting persisting was because I was trying to flush the bucket in a different thread without realising that the flush operation can take some time. By the time the documents were persisted, the flush operation hadn't finished and when it actually did it removed the documents that i was persisting. But your answer is still valid. I had to use flatmap for this little operation i am doing here. Thanks :)

Comment: Oh okay, those details were missing from the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use .`flatMap` instead of .`map`. You inner stream is not getting subscribed to.

Comment: `.block()` method is explicitly called

Comment: .block() subscribes to the outer stream. bucket.upsert returns a stream and has to be subscribed to. flatmap does that, not map. However, I am not sure OP's code even compiles as bucket.upsert returns an Observable<T>.

Comment: ah, in case `bucket.upsert` returns Observable, your proposal should help then

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved this issue regarding couchbase and its state not totally updated after block

More notes on this issue.  It was actually not an error but Couchbase uses a scanning consistency for its internal indexes of UNBOUNDED.  This means that if any creates, deletes, etc are performed on couchbase then its internal state takes a tiny amount of time to reindex.  This was causing the intermittent behavour when running the reactor service.  Especially when doing a bulk create followed by a get items.  Using the query option command QueryOptions.queryOptions().scanConsistency(QueryScanConsistency.REQUEST_PLUS) forced couchbase to update its indexes prior to running the query.  This is exactly the behaviour we need and putting this in fixed all this shit ive been having.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same issue regarding upserting items into couchbase with a `block()` then performing a get without the items being there.  There seems to be an tiny amount of time after a `block()` to an upsert before a get can find the items.   This is not the expected behaviour of a `block()` which should complete.

If i do create

```
Thread.sleep(5000)

GetItems
```

It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need this added to your query

It basically waits until all indexes have been completed internally on the couchbase before proceeding with the query.  It fixed my issues where i had a bulk upsert and then tried to do a get items which was returning an inconsistent number of rows (simply based on how many couchbase indexes had been fully resolved internally).  Nasty symptoms but this is your path to glory!

```
QueryOptions.queryOptions().scanConsistency(QueryScanConsistency.REQUEST_PLUS)
```